# Why did Om and Shanti have different fates when they died?

Tags: plot-explanation, om-shanti-om

In the 2007 Indian film *[Om Shanti Om](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Shanti_Om)*, Om Makhija and Shanti are caught in a fire and, as we discover by the end of the film, both of them died that night. However, Om is reincarnated as Om Kapoor, while Shanti becomes a ghost who ultimately haunts Mukesh.

Why did they have different fates? Why didn't Shanti reincarnate like Om?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer given directly in the film so it's more based on my analysis of the movie.

**Om:** He got dreams to fulfill. His incomplete wishes; His love for Shanti and his passion for being a star which never got fulfilled. And also before dying he got hit by a car with a pregnant woman and he rebirthed from that woman only. So his soul did get a chance too.

**Shanti:** Her dreams were broken, the guy used her and killed her. She got no dreams left to fulfill, only revenge was left. And she died alone in a fire with all the pain.